# disable (or trim) logging of bytea requests in postgres

Tags: logging, database, postgresql

Our application store some big blob (bytea) in a separate database every 30 minutes. It's fine and we want to keep it like, this, but it's causing crazy logging:

2021-01-25 11:11:00 UTC postgres109432 INSERT DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '127.0.0.1', $2 = '\x0101006a6176612e7574696c2e486173684d61f0019db7320101636f6d2e777a2e7461636f2e6267702e666565642e636f6c6c6563746f722e646f6d61696e2e5072656669f801013139322e34392e3134362e302f32b40102636f6d2e777a2e7461636f2e6267702e666565642e636f6c6c6563746f722e646f6d.... (hundreds of megabytes here).

Is there a way to trim or disable bytea logging for postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `log_parameter_max_length` setting in your logging config.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-logging.html  to get the full story on how logging configuration variables interact.

You can probably change logging level to make it go away as well. But you want to be careful with logging full parameters because you could be exposing data through that route.